# Facebook crashed then Chromium wont start?

Tags: chromium, facebook, crash

i can't start Chromium anymore

try to write this at terminal

```
chromium-browser
```

and i had got error

```
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs/libnet.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3net12WebSogketJob14SaveNextCookieEv
```

i want to backup Chromium settings,

how can i solve it ? without lose (saved usernames, bookmarks, .. etc)

i read many another questions and answers and can't solve this problem.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get --reinstall install chromium-browser`

Comment: without lose (saved usernames, bookmarks, .. etc) ?

Comment: Yes. for assuarance Press Ctrl+H on File browser and make a copy of the `/home/USER/.config/chromium` folder. If problem comes, replace the new folder with the backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **reinstall** the chromium-browser without purging, you dont loss Usernames and Bookmarks

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install chromium-browser
```

Username and Bookmarks are stored in `/home/USER/.config/chromium` folder.

For assuarance Press Ctrl+H on File browser to see the hidden (Ex `.config`) folders.

Then make a copy of the `/home/USER/.config/chromium` folder. If problem comes, you can replace the new folder with the backup.